# Get list of accounts via Google Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

Ultimately, I am trying to get all reviews for a business location.

I have gone through the basic setup guide here https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup

I have access to the project in Google Cloud Platform and am a manager in Google My Business.

To test things, I am using the OAuth 2.0 Playground. I tried calling https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts but it just returns details of my own account:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "vettedState": "NOT_VETTED", 
      "type": "PERSONAL", 
      "name": "accounts/1234567890", 
      "verificationState": "UNVERIFIED", 
      "accountName": "account name"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting to see details of the business account?

I tried calling https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/1234567890/locations/qwertyuiop/reviews but get this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND", 
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.", 
    "code": 404
  }
}
```

This feels like a permissions problem but I cannot find any information about the requirements or any helpful information at all!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bearer authorization token needs to generated using the Google account that actually has access to the locations. You seem to be using your personal Google account. Please take a look at the [basic setup guide from the documentation on making a simple HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request):

Steps 1-6 are about your application and the general access to the GBP APIs.

Step 7-8 are about using the Google account that actually has access to the location data. So here, **you need to use the business's Google account that has location ownership.**

Comment: I just tried that and I get an error saying "read_mask" is required. I added "?read_mask=name" to the call and then got "Requested entity was not found". I know a locationId but calling the "reviews" endpoint also gave the same error.

Comment: But ?readMask=name gives the error "Requested entity was not found" - why is that? As in my question, I am unable to get the account details which has the reviews using https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts so maybe it's a permissions issue? Problem is I don't know if it is and/or what permission I might be missing

Comment: What account details were you looking for? The personal account does not have more details, you are getting the full account details response.

Comment: That's the issue - I want to get the reviews for the business, but only get my personal account details. Am working on developing a plugin that we can use on client websites, not just our own. How do I get the business account details & location(s) and reviews?

Comment: You would have to guide your users through an Oauth flow so they can grant your application access to their GBP locations and thus reviews: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/oauth-setup